# C++ input and output files

Tags: c++

So im writing c++ program, that takes a integer from input file, multiply it with 2 and outputs it on output file. So the code is -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    FILE * inFile;
    FILE * outFile;
    inFile = fopen ("reiz.in","r");
    outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","r+");
    fscanf (inFile, "%s", n);
    int m = n * 2;
    fprintf (outFile, "%n", n);
    fclose (inFile);
    fclose (outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

But something is wrong. in reiz.in file there is number 2, after running program it should output 4 in reiz.out, but it just shows don't send error. What exactly is wrong with my script?
Best regards,
Y2oK

EDIT 1: Ok now it looks like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    FILE * inFile;
    FILE * outFile;
    inFile = fopen ("reiz.in","r");
    outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","r+");
    fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
    int m = n * 2;
    fprintf (outFile, "%d", m);
    fclose (inFile);
    fclose (outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

but still it gives same don't send error when running reiz.exe file, and it doesn't write anything on output file
I'm now a little bit confused, and don't know who to chose as best answer, so I will chose the one who got most "+1". But thanks to all!

Comment: You are still not passing the *address* of `n` to `fscanf()`.  Do yourself a favor, use `fstream` instead!

Comment: I've edited the question now, so you can copy it complete.

Comment: @Y2ok: please use patience and due diligence. You have had good answers. You dismiss them with `I can't compile`, `same don't send` (?), `Still didn't help` and `Same problem :/`. This means you obviously did not try the corrections - correctly. People will run out of patience and then `Still didn't help` will become true: **You** didn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a C-program (apart from the `using namespace std;`). In C++ you should use streams and formatted I/O, like this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input_file("reiz.in");
    int n;
    input_file >> n; // read one integer
    std::ostream output_file("reis.out");
    output_file << n * 2 << std::endl; // calculate n * 2 and write the result
                                       // to a file. std::endl adds a newline and
                                       // flushes the buffer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't compile your program with dev-c++ compiler.

Comment: @Y2ok:  Please throw that pile-of-crap compiler away.  If you're on Windows, use VisualStudio Express.  If on Linux, use GCC.

Comment: Hmm, I am learning c++ from this site - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/ , is there maybe site. If that's not c++ what is it? And where can I learn c++ if it's not c++ ?

Comment: @Y2ok: While `cstdio` is valid C++, it is a legacy C interface.  C++ provides a new, less error-prone and type-safe solution for working with files: `iostream`.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: @Y2ok: That is is OK for a start, but you are reading the part about the C Standard library. If you really want to learn C++, get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: @Y2ok: You may also check out http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/lv/start, maybe better to read in your own native language. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the address of `n` to `fscanf()` (and it's an integer not a string):

```
fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
```

All that stuff is a bit long in the tooth, unless you are actually writing 'C'.  Look at the `iostream` family of classes if you are writing 'C++'

Comment: You didn't pass the address of `n` did you: `fscanf (inFile, "%d", n);`

Comment: Hmm, I am learning c++ from this site - cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio , is there maybe site. If that's not c++ what is it? And where can I learn c++ if it's not c++ ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

This is a C include, not a C++ include.  Instead, you should use:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

---

```
fscanf (inFile, "%s", n);
```

The format `%s` is for strings, of type `char*`.  You want to read a decimal number, so use `%d` instead.  Furthermore, you have to pass the *address*  of the destination:

```
fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
```

---

```
fprintf (outFile, "%n", n);
```

The format `%n` is used to query the number of bytes written so far, and requires a pointer.  Since you want to write a decimal number, use `%d` again:

```
fprintf (outFile, "%d", n);
```

Comment: Changed, but same don't send after starting the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Go use iostream (Bjorns answer)

But I think

```
outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","r+");
```

should be

```
outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","w+");
```

Also

```
fscanf (inFile, "%d", n);
```

should be

```
fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
```

For ease of reference, a fully working (**C**) program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    FILE * inFile;
    FILE * outFile;
    inFile = fopen ("reiz.in","r");
    outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","w+");
    fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
    int m = n * 2;
    fprintf (outFile, "%i", m);
    fclose (inFile);
    fclose (outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Y2ok: you're welcome. Try it (I had a typo earlier, so see whether you missed my edit?)

Comment: Open mode `"r+"` is fine if the output file exists.  If it should be created by the program, it must be `"w"` or `"w+"`.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: exactly the point. If it doesn't exist, the fprintf fails spectacularly because there is no error handling

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I am learning c++ from this site - cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio . If that's not c++ what is it? And where can I learn c++ if it's not c++ ?

Comment: It says **[`clibrary`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/)** right there in the url. Learn c++ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890007/c-input-and-output-files/7890086#7890086) or [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with `fscanf`.  First, your format string is wrong -- you're taking a string, where you should be taking a (signed?) decimal.  Second, you are passing `n` by-value, but you should be passing a pointer to `n` instead:

```
fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
```

You are also `#include`ing the now-deprecated `<stdio.h>` file.  You should:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Finally, you **claim** to be writing C++ code, but the code you actually wrote is decidedly not C++-ish, which is to say it is type-unsafe.  I'd recommend you either go C++, or don't -- don't pussyfoot around.

Here is a more C++ way of doing what you're trying to do (you should add error-checking and writing to the output file):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in("reiz.in", std::ios::in);
    int n = 0;
    in >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues which will prevent your code from working properly.

1. There is no need to open `outfile` as `r+`.  You can just open it with mode `w`.

   ```
   outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","w");
   ```
2. When you read from the file with `fscanf`, you are passing the integer `n` instead of the pointer to the integer `n`.  `fscanf` is expecting to receive the *location* to write the integer it read.  You are passing the integer itself (which will, in the best case, crash your program.  Worst case, weird stuff will start happening).

   ```
   fscanf (inFile, "%s", &n);
   ```
3. You are using `%n` when writing to outfile.  This does not print the integer `n` but rather it reads the number of bytes written so far.  You want to use `%d` instead.

   ```
   fprintf (outFile, "%d", m);
   ```

Also, as a side-note, you seem to be using C instead of C++.  In C++, you would usually use file stream objects, like `ifstream` and `ofstream`, to read from and write to files.  You are using things like `fopen` which are decidedly more C-like.

This code should work better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    FILE * inFile;
    FILE * outFile;
    inFile = fopen ("reiz.in","r");
    outFile = fopen ("reiz.out","w");
    fscanf (inFile, "%d", &n);
    int m = n * 2;
    fprintf (outFile, "%d\n", m);
    fclose (inFile);
    fclose (outFile);
    return 0;
}
```